# How to open Google Sheets spreadsheet to cell in a single row that contains today's date

Tags: javascript, date, google-sheets, editor

I'm trying to set a Google Sheet document open to the cell in row 2 with the current date using Script Editor. The dates are arranged chronologically, and daily, from A2:IK2.  They're formatted mm/dd.

I found one answer on this website for a similar question, however their dates were listed in a single column whereas my dates are in a single row.  The following code was posted by Marshmallow here: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/78927/how-to-make-google-sheet-jump-to-todays-row-when-opened).

Marshmallow's answer:

```
function onOpen() {
 var menu = [{name: "Jump to today's date", functionName: "jumpToDate"}];
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu("Custom", menu);
 jumpToDate();
}

function jumpToDate() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
 var range = sheet.getRange("A:A");
 var values = range.getValues();  
 var day = 24*3600*1000;  
 var today = parseInt((new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0))/day);  
 var ssdate; 
 for (var i=0; i<values.length; i++) {
   try {
     ssdate = values[i][0].getTime()/day;
   }
   catch(e) {
   }
   if (ssdate && Math.floor(ssdate) == today) {
     sheet.setActiveRange(range.offset(i,0,1,1));
     break;
   }    
 }
}
```

I modified it to:

```
function onOpen() {
 var menu = [{name: "Jump to today's date", functionName: "jumpToDate"}];
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu("Custom", menu);
 jumpToDate();
}

function jumpToDate() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
 var range = sheet.getRange("A2:IK2");  //given that it is in row 2
 var values = range.getValues();  
 var day = 24*3600*1000;  
 var today = ((new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0))/day);  
 var ssdate; 
 for (var i=0; i<values.length; i++) {
   try {
     ssdate = values[i][0].getTime()/day;
   }
   catch(e) {
   }
   if (ssdate && Math.floor(ssdate) == today) {
     sheet.setActiveRange(range.offset(0,i,1,1));  //to offset columns not rows
     break;
   }    
 }
}
```

I thought that I had accounted for the transposition from rows to columns (range "A:A" to "A2:IK2" and changing the offset where indicated; however, I am not seeing the code have any effect.  Let alone opening to today's date.

What am I missing here?  Any suggestions?

Comment: Note that `((new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0))/day)` really doesn't need all those brackets, consider: `new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0) / day`. And unless your time zone is GMT, the result will have a decimal part as you're setting the local hours to zero, not UTC hours, so not whole days since the epoch so `Math.floor(ssdate) == today` (which truncates the decimal part) will never be true unless your time zone is GMT (so there is no decimal part).

Answer (score 1):

Two more places where transposition requires changes are: `values[0][i]` instead of `values[i][0]`, and `values[0].length` instead of `values.length`.

To address RobG's remark, I also changed the comparison logic, replacing division and flooring with straightforward inequalities: the current time must be between the beginning and end of the date stated in the spreadsheet.

```
function onOpen() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange("2:2");   // get all 2nd row
  var values = range.getValues();
  var day = 24*3600*1000;  
  var now = Date.now();  
  var ssdate; 
  for (var i = 0; i < values[0].length; i++) {
    try {
      ssdate = values[0][i].getTime();
    }
    catch(e) {
    }
    if (ssdate && ssdate <= now && now < ssdate + day) {
      sheet.setActiveRange(range.offset(0,i,1,1));
      break;
    }    
  }
}
```

Comment: Meta, this is perfect. Thank you so much! The simplification definitely cleaned it up a bit.  And your explanation makes sense in hindsight. Thanks again!

Comment: No problem; on Stack Exchange, an answer that solves the problem can be marked as "accepted" by clicking the checkmark to the left of it.